# How to use cloc to find lines of code in a debian package

Tags: directory, utilities

cloc - statistics utility to count lines of code

Now the manpage mentions that it can be used to count lines of code of a tarball

```
cloc perl-5.10.0.tar.gz
```

Now a debian package is just like a compressed tarball. Is there a way to use cloc.

I tried :-

```
[$] cloc cloc_1.60-1.1_all.deb                                                                                                    
       0 text files.
       0 unique files.                              
       1 file ignored.
```

The output isn't correct. I tried to see how many files are in the debian package and saw :-

```
[$] dpkg -L cloc                                                                                                                
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/cloc.1.gz
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/cloc
/usr/share/doc/cloc/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/cloc/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/cloc/copyright
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/cloc
```

So either it's a bug in cloc or I didn't apply it correctly. For the record, I have downloaded the debian package of cloc to use as an example (as it's small).

```
[$] ls -lh cloc_1.60-1.1_all.deb                                                                                             
-rw-r--r-- 1 shirish shirish 88K Jul 24  2015 cloc_1.60-1.1_all.deb
```

Look forward for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run `cloc` on the source package, not on the binary package — `cloc_1.60-1.1_all.deb` is the binary package.

This works:

```
dget -d http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/pool/main/c/cloc/cloc_1.60-1.1.dsc
cloc cloc_1.60.orig.tar.gz
```

and shows

```
      12 text files.
       7 unique files.                              
       9 files ignored.

http://cloc.sourceforge.net v 1.60  T=0.05 s (57.3 files/s, 176957.8 lines/s)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Language                     files          blank        comment           code
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Perl                             2            666            978           7477
make                             1             26             35             75
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SUM:                             3            692           1013           7552
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

`dget` downloads the source package *via* the given descriptor, and `-d` tells it not to extract the source. You'll find `dget` in the `devscripts` package.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is possible to count code directly with the .deb file--assuming the .deb file contains source code--using cloc's --extract-with switch:

```
cloc --extract-with='dpkg-deb -x >FILE< .' ../cloc_1.60-1_all.deb 
       2 text files.
       2 unique files.                              
       1 file ignored.

https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc v 1.66  T=0.09 s (11.3 files/s, 102181.3 lines/s)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Language                     files          blank        comment           code
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Perl                             1            661            966           7437
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

That's kind of clunky though. I will add native support for .deb files in the next release of cloc (to be 1.68).

Also note the difference in counts between the tarball and the .deb:  the tarball contains the full source distribution while the latter only has the final tool to be installed.  Since the cloc is all source code, it can be counted; if it were compiled, counting the .deb wouldn't work.  This trick won't work with most .deb files as most of them (I'm guessing) contain compiled executables.